# Java split not working as expected for string "--"

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to break a paragraph based on the string "--" in a complete line and the paragraph looks like below. i have to break if a line contains only "--" only i cannot split based on line as i have some other limitation.

```
Hi Hello this is -- to test

--

java split function -- test
```

Expected output.

```
["Hi Hello this is -- to test", "java split function -- test"]
```

i tried the below code and it did not work

```
searchValue.split("--")
```

and

```
searchValue.split("\n--\n")
```

both of them have not worked. and is splitting for all "--"  in a line

any idea how i should write the split in this case

Exact input string:

```
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log:Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell 
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Type help() for help on available commands
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Connecting to t3://0.0.0.0:6300 with userid system ...
start_check_state.log-Successfully connected to Admin Server '' that belongs to domain 'dev'.
--
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:05.963 [INFO ] <CIA> - <session.CIADispatcherBean> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Activate Maintenance Ticket> - [event :alarmKey=JOB PROCESS,srcSystem=CIA Planned Maintenance]
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:05.965 [INFO ] <CIA> - <em.CIAEventQueue> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Activate Maintenance Ticket> - COMPLETED
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.039 [INFO ] <CIA> - <messagelisteners.MessageListenerDelegate> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Close Maintenance Ticket> - message handling started. sequence = [-1115362510203642553] node = 
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.040 [INFO ] <CIA> - <dispatcher.MDBProcessor> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Close Maintenance Ticket> - CIA Event <JOB PROCESS> processing on <>
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.043 [INFO ] <CIA> - <dispatcher.MDBProcessor> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Close Maintenance Ticket> - CIA Event <JOB PROCESS> was successfully processed on <>
cia.log.2017-07-20:10.07.2017 6:00:06.044 [INFO ] <CIA> - <messagelisteners.MessageListenerDelegate> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Close Maintenance Ticket> - message processed. sequence = [-1115362510203642553] node =  
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.058 [INFO ] <CIA> - <messagelisteners.MessageListenerDelegate> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Activate Maintenance Ticket> - message handling started. sequence = [-1115362510203642553] node = test123
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.060 [INFO ] <CIA> - <dispatcher.MDBProcessor> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Activate Maintenance Ticket> - CIA Event <JOB PROCESS> processing on <>
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.063 [INFO ] <CIA> - <dispatcher.MDBProcessor> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Activate Maintenance Ticket> - CIA Event <JOB PROCESS> was successfully processed on <>
cia.log.2017-07-20-10.07.2017 6:00:06.064 [INFO ] <CIA> - <messagelisteners.MessageListenerDelegate> - <Flow_Id Alarm_Id/NC_Id : JOB PROCESS> <EventType : Activate Maintenance Ticket> - message processed. sequence = [-1115362510203642553] node = 
--
cpm_.log-2017-07-10 05:27:53 INFO  com..solutions.tfnurg.toms.cpm.job.BorrowedEquipmentNotificationJob :29 - Job for creating notification tasks started.
cpm_.log-2017-07-10 05:27:53 INFO  com..solutions.tfnurg.toms.cpm.bean.impl.test123 :471 - All required remind tasks created without any errors
cpm_.log:2017-07-10 05:27:53 INFO  com..solutions.tfnurg.toms.cpm.job.BorrowedEquipmentNotificationJob :46 - Created Notification Tasks: 
cpm_.log-2017-07-10 05:27:53 INFO  com..solutions.tfnurg.toms.cpm.job.BorrowedEquipmentNotificationJob :34 - Job for creating notification tasks ended.
--
```

Comment: Define "not worked", show your exact code, the current and expected output.

Comment: One thing could be the type of newline character combination, which would be \r\n for Windows, not \n.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. `.split("--")` works as expected

Comment: Perhaps, both the line endings and dashes are different from what you think. Try `split("\\R\\s*\\p{Pd}{2}\\s*\\R+")`. Could you please provide the input as an exact Java string literal?

Comment: Your code [appears to be working for me](http://rextester.com/XZUMD3661).

Comment: What about `Stream.of(str.split("\n--\n")).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());` ?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Why would you expect that to behave any differently than a regular regex string split?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's all about trimming lines, assuming the expected result is `["Hi Hello this is -- to test", "java split function -- test"]`

Comment: Huh?  The OP has an issue with the regex split not working, not the trimming of lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried it. It did not work.

Comment: Then you have no `-` or line breaks. Most probably because it is HTML and line breaks you see are `<br/>` / `<br>`. Or the `-`s are some kind of entities that must be decoded as `-` before you apply a regex.

Comment: Can you check the octet representation of your text fragment (ie. using a hex editor) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my string is a big string it is not working

Comment: @user2727493 What do you mean with 'big string'? Haven't you posted the complete original string you operate on ? In case you haven't, please do so.

Comment: @user2727493: Works for me (see [here](https://ideone.com/0MVEAo)). Can you show the code that feeds your variable `searchValue`?

Answer (score 4):

You should search for both `\n` (newline) and/or `\r` (carriage return).

Try this regex:

```
[\n\r]+--[\n\r]+
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/huPete/1

In Java:

```
searchValue.split("[\\n\\r]+--[\\n\\r]+")
```

Comment: @user2727493 I've copied and pasted your supplied input string to my program. Works fine in my compiler. Can you specify how are you getting this string? From any service or written somewhere in file, DB etc??

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me, perhaps there is strange whitespace as suggested by the other answers & comments.

Here's a demo showing the input and output you hoped for: https://ideone.com/1vKnrm

Input:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276416/java-split-not-working-as-expected-for-string
 */
class JavaSplitTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String searchValue = "Hi Hello this is -- to test\n" +
      "\n" +
      "--\n" +
      "\n" +
      "java split function -- test\n";

    String[] splitted = searchValue.split("\n--\n");

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitted));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[Hi Hello this is -- to test
, 
java split function -- test
]
```